# Mysql count group by several criteria

Tags: mysql

An example of a table that I use looks:

```
    id_user  | process_number |    date   
  ---------------------------------------
      01     |        1       | 2012-05-04
      01     |        1       | 2012-05-04
      02     |        0       | 2012-05-04
      01     |        1       | 2012-05-05
      01     |        2       | 2012-05-05
      01     |        0       | 2012-05-05
      02     |        0       | 2012-05-05
      03     |        1       | 2012-05-05
      04     |        2       | 2012-05-05
      05     |        1       | 2012-05-05
      05     |        1       | 2012-05-05
      06     |        0       | 2012-05-05
      07     |        3       | 2012-05-05
```

The result that I want to get is the number of unique processes (group by id_user), number of total process (group by date) and count distinct user when process_number is not equal to "0" (grouped by date and by user). I've tried to achieve this with query:

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT id_user ) AS user_process, COUNT( * ) AS total_process, DATE( date) AS date_process, SUM( IF( process_number = '0', 0, 1 ) ) notification FROM a_proces GROUP BY DATE( date ) ORDER BY DATE( date ) DESC LIMIT 0 , 10
```

This query adds all users in a given day, who had more than one process_number that is greater than zero in notification column. The correct result in this example should look like:

```
 date_process    |       user_process       |        total_process     |  notification
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   2012-05-04    |            2             |              3           |       1
   2012-05-05    |            7             |              10          |       6
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the following:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( date, '%d/%m/%Y' ) AS date_process,
  COUNT(DISTINCT id_user) AS user_process, 
  COUNT( * ) AS total_process, 
  count(distinct case when process_number <> 0 then id_user end) notification 
FROM a_proces 
GROUP BY DATE( date ) 
ORDER BY DATE( date ) DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 10;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2cb7/9)

If the notification result that you want is the total count of each distinct `process_number` for each `id_user`, then you can use:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( p.date, '%d/%m/%Y' ) AS date_process,
  COUNT(DISTINCT p.id_user) AS user_process, 
  COUNT( * ) AS total_process, 
  d.notification 
FROM a_proces p
INNER JOIN
(
  select count(process_number) notification, date
  from
  (
    select distinct id_user, process_number,
      DATE_FORMAT( date, '%d/%m/%Y' ) date
    from a_proces
    where process_number <> 0
  ) d
  group by date
) d
  on DATE_FORMAT( p.date, '%d/%m/%Y' )  = d.date
GROUP BY DATE( p.date ), d.notification
ORDER BY DATE( p.date ) DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 10;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2cb7/26)